# Dynamically adding list of hyperlinked images to web document

Tags: javascript, loops, appendchild

I was working on organizing a bunch of images into folders and then creating a web page so I can views them all in a nice little package. I've normalized all files and folders to be named by a basic numeric pattern.  I was able to display all of the images nicely but now I want to have them all link to their respective folders.

I may not be understanding the problem well enough to be able to do an appropriate search for the answer. I'm thinking all I need to do is append my image node to an anchor node somehow.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<body>

<div id="volumeCovers"></div>
<script>
  var container = document.getElementById('volumeCovers');
  var images = 12;
  for (var i = 1; i <= images; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('src', 'volumes/pics/v' + i + '.jpg');
    container.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>

<body>
```

Comment: What is the problem? it's not clear enough.

Comment: sorry, i writed 'link' in create tag instant of 'a'; i rewrite my code, i hope that all right.

Comment: If a link goes to a respective folder...does this folder have a page.html?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your image in links and add to container:

```
   for (var i = 1; i <= images; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href','url');
        link.append(img);    
        img.setAttribute('src', 'volumes/pics/v' + i + '.jpg');
        container.appendChild(link);
      }
```

'url' replace to  necessary adress. 
Maybe also necessary edit of css.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response but the code you provided yielded a blank screen. I reviewed for typos and still no success.  You guys are great.  Is there perhaps something you may have missed?

Comment: I had to modify the following line to get this to work:  let link = document.createElement('link')    was changed to  let link = document.createElement('a')